# WebGL not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, three.js

My website uses a webgl background which lags in Chrome for Mac. All other browsers, including Chrome for windows, load the website correctly. I have seen that setting the force color profile to srgb on chrome fixes the issue on my personal computer, however the issue persists for other visitors. Is there a way to fix this? Here is a jsfiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/ovmy52uc/
Here is the code-

```
var SEPARATION = 100, AMOUNTX = 50, AMOUNTY = 50;
var container;
var camera, scene, renderer;
var particles, particle, count = 0;
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
init();
animate();
function init() {
container = $('.webgl .background');
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / 
window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
camera.position.z = 1000;
scene = new THREE.Scene();
particles = new Array();
var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
var material = new THREE.SpriteCanvasMaterial( {
color: 0xffffff,
program: function ( context ) {
context.beginPath();
context.arc( 0, 0, 0.5, 0, PI2, true );
context.fill();
}
} );
var i = 0;
for ( var ix = 0; ix < AMOUNTX; ix ++ ) {
for ( var iy = 0; iy < AMOUNTY; iy ++ ) {
particle = particles[ i ++ ] = new THREE.Sprite( material );
particle.position.x = ix * SEPARATION - ( ( AMOUNTX * SEPARATION ) / 2 
);
particle.position.z = iy * SEPARATION - ( ( AMOUNTY * SEPARATION ) / 2 
);
scene.add( particle );
}
}
renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
$(container).append( renderer.domElement );
document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false 
);
document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false );
//
window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
}
function onWindowResize() {
windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}
//
function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
mouseY = event.clientY - windowHalfY;
}
function onDocumentTouchStart( event ) {
if ( event.touches.length === 1 ) {
// event.preventDefault();
mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
mouseY = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - windowHalfY;
}
}
function onDocumentTouchMove( event ) {
if ( event.touches.length === 1 ) {
// event.preventDefault();
mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
mouseY = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - windowHalfY;
}
}
//
function animate() {
requestAnimationFrame( animate );
render();
}
function render() {
camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .05;
camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .05;
camera.lookAt( scene.position );
var i = 0;
for ( var ix = 0; ix < AMOUNTX; ix ++ ) {
for ( var iy = 0; iy < AMOUNTY; iy ++ ) {
particle = particles[ i++ ];
particle.position.y = ( Math.sin( ( ix + count ) * 0.3 ) * 50 ) +
( Math.sin( ( iy + count ) * 0.5 ) * 50 );
particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = ( Math.sin( ( ix + count ) * 0.3 
) + 1 ) * 4 +
( Math.sin( ( iy + count ) * 0.5 ) + 1 ) * 4;
}
}
renderer.render( scene, camera );
count += 0.1;
}
```

Loading the page outside of the jsfiddle, makes it even slower on Chrome for Mac. Thanks in advance

Comment: The animation was smooth and working fine here. I'm on Chrome for Mac.

Comment: @Niloct That's weird, I've tried it on two mac computers with chrome. Is it slow compared to other browsers, or would you say the smoothness is about the same?

Comment: They work the same, Firefox and Safari. I'm on 10.13.4 High Sierra, 8GB RAM.

Comment: Make sure: `chrome://flags/#ignore-gpu-blacklist` is enabled, your script is not laggy for me in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two things that would cause lag.
this line:
`renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );`
Which will make the resolution of your canvas quite large on high DPI monitors.
Try removing it.

And the for loops in your render function.

Comment: I was just wondering if you knew why that would only cause a problem in chrome?

Comment: I don't know, but try using chrome dev tools to check the performance, that should tell you where the bottleneck is.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `CanvasRenderer`, you are not using WebGL but a Canvas 2D rendering context. Try to use `WebGLRenderer` instead. I'm sure you will have a better performance.